# imagePickerController won't return camera photo. Will return album photo

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

i'm loading photos from my library just fine, but photos coming from he camera don't display in the imageView. I've set allowsImageEditing = YES. I've also used CFShow(info) and the data from the camera is not nil...

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on the [allowsEditing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/allowsEditing) property of the UIImagePicker? If not, it's not going to return you an editedImage. You'll probably want:

> [UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_information_keys)

Comment: allowsImageEditing is set to YES for both source types

Answer (score 0):

I know this is many months later, but I struggled with the same problem and found that though it was asked here many times, it was never answered. Well, I'm happy to say that I figured it out and so am posting it on a few of the nearly-identical questions that come up first on a search.

I posted the full answer here:
[didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo return nil photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088874/didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-return-nil-photo/4192109)