# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo return nil photo

Tags: iphone, uiimage, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working to capture an image that is returned in 4.0 using

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 

    // MediaType can be kUTTypeImage or kUTTypeMovie. If it's a movie then you
    // can get the URL to the actual file itself. This example only looks for images.
    //   
    NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    // NSString* videoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    // Try getting the edited image first. If it doesn't exist then you get the
    // original image.
    //
    if (CFStringCompare((CFStringRef) mediaType,  kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {               
        UIImage* picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        if (!picture)
            picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];             

        // **picture is always nil
            // info dictionary count = 1


    }

}
```

What is happening is that the info dictionary always returns with a single entry:

> {
>           UIImagePickerControllerMediaType =
>   "public.image";

which is great, but there is never an image.

I was using a great example from this forum to do this, and I am pretty sure the calls are correct, but never an image.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any takers?  Huge Karma bump on this one!!!!

Answer (score 53):

I know this is many months later, but I struggled with this for hours, and found this same question all over this site and iphonedevsdk.com, but never with a working answer.

To summarize, if the image was picked from the camera roll/photo library it worked fine, but if the image was a new photo take with the camera it never worked. Well, here's how to make it work for both:

You have to dismiss and release the UIImagePickerController **before** you try to do anything with the info dictionary. To be super-clear:

**This DOES NOT work:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
                      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

          // No good with the edited image (if you allowed editing)
  myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
          // AND no good with the original image
  myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
          // AND no doing some other kind of assignment
  UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [picker release];
}
```

In all of those cases the image will be nil.

However, via the magic of releasing the UIImagePickerController *first...*

**This DOES work:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
                      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [picker release];

          // Edited image works great (if you allowed editing)
  myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
          // AND the original image works great
  myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
          // AND do whatever you want with it, (NSDictionary *)info is fine now
  UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

Crazy simple, but that's all there is to it.

Comment: are you for serious!?!  is this what my problem has been!  OMG.  *_dies_*

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but a couple of options come to mind as possibilities. The first is to copy the info dictionary -- `NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:info]` -- and then nil out the picker -- `picker = nil`. Not sure if that'll work. The other option that almost assuredly will work is to create a separate file for the image picking code in Xcode and set that file to not use ARC, keeping the solution here.

Comment: thanks.. I got it working but the way around. I dismiss the camera after setting the uiimage. I don't know this maybe a bug on ios.

Comment: Wow. I came across a similar problem and this did the job. Now I'm curious why does this work?

Answer (score 17):

whilst Matthew Frederick's answer is most popular and has long been the appropriate response, as of iOS 5.0, apple made available `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, to replace the now deprecated (as of iOS 6.0) `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`.

performing the image info dictionary retrieval in the completion block should hopefully make more sense to all.

to take his example from above, it would now look like:

```
- (void)    imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
          // Edited image works great (if you allowed editing)
        myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
          // AND the original image works great
        myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
          // AND do whatever you want with it, (NSDictionary *)info is fine now
        UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    }];
}
```

Comment: You sure its `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:` and not `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void)` ?

Comment: This still produces a nil result for me, running an iPhone app in the iPad emulator (iOS 6.1).

Comment: Actually it seems like it's a longstanding bug in the iPad emulator since iOS 5 - even though it seems to work on the real device. Strange. So the only solution is to use the asset library...

Answer (score 4):

I've tried all above, but no luck on iPad 6.0/6.1 simulator, however i've found that info contains "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" key and here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

  UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  if(NULL == image){
      [MyImageLoader loadImageFromAssertByUrl:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]
                                   completion:^(UIImage* img){
                                        //img not null here
                                   }];
  }else{
      //image not null here
  }
}
```

and code for loadImageFromAssertByUrl is:

```
+(void) loadImageFromAssertByUrl:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(UIImage*)) completion{
  ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [assetLibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
      ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
      Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
      NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
      UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      completion(img);
  } failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
  }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe we need to do this kind of thing to work around a bug in the iPad emulator that was reported at least a year ago, but at least it can be worked around...

Answer (score 2):

There's also a known bug with some versions of XCode and Mountain Lion. Check your console for this message:

`2013-01-17 21:36:34.946 3sure-ios[5341:1803] Named service 'com.apple.PersistentURLTranslator.Gatekeeper' not found. assetsd is down or misconfigured. Things will not work the way you expect them to.`

It probably won't work if that message appears. Check your app at the actual iOS device.

Nevetheless, restarting both simulator and XCode seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I did not see this error, but on simulator the image is null on device it works...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms, but in my case it turned out I had a category on something in the UIImagePickerController hierarchy that overrode "uuid" or "setUUID"?  I guess CoreData needs these methods or it gets very, very confused, and the asset library is all CoreData stuff.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] initWithNibName:(NSString *) bundle:(NSBundle *)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    //Image picker for nil value 
    UIImage* selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSLog(@"my Info :: %@", info);

    if(NULL == selectedImage){
      UIImage * selectedImage =  [PhotoViewController loadImageFromAssertByUrl:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]
                                     completion:^(UIImage * selectedImage){
                                         //img not null here
                                         NSLog(@"img2 ::: %@", selectedImage);
                                         uploadImg.image = selectedImage;
                                         [self.view addSubview:PermissionView];
                                     }];
    }else{
        //image not null here
        NSLog(@"Up IMG00 :: %@", uploadImg.image);
        NSLog(@"Sel IMG00 :: %@", selectedImage);
        uploadImg.image = [selectedImage retain];
        NSLog(@"Up IMG22 :: %@", uploadImg.image);
        NSLog(@"Sel IMG22 :: %@", selectedImage);

    }
}


+(UIImage *) loadImageFromAssertByUrl:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(UIImage*)) completion{


    __block UIImage* img;

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [assetLibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
        NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
        img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        completion(img);
        NSLog(@"img ::: %@", img);
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }];

    return img;
}
```

Comment: I had same issue in iPad air and iOS 8, and I solved my problem this codes. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Following Steps needs to be followed: 
1) Make UIActionSheet 
2) On selection necessary source type - load resrouces 
3) didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo - set image from image Dictionary recieved

```
    - (IBAction)actionButtonUpload:(id)sender {

             UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self 

cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera",@"Photo Library", nil];

         [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

    }

    #pragma mark -- UIActionSheet Delegate
    -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        UIAlertView *alert;


        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

                    NSLog(@"No camera!");
                    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


                } else {

                    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alumnikonnect" message:@"Camera is not available, please select a different media" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                    [alert show];

                }
                break;
            case 1:

                if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

                    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


                } else {

                    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alumnikonnect" message:@"Photolibrary is not available, please select a different media" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                    [alert show];

                }

                break;

        }

    }


    #pragma mark - Image picker delegate

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
          self.imageEventPic.layer.cornerRadius =   self.imageEventPic.frame.size.height /2;
          self.imageEventPic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
          self.imageEventPic.layer.borderWidth = 0;
          self.imageEventPic.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
          self.imageEventPic.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.212 green:0.255 blue:0.302 alpha:1.000].CGColor;


        self.labelUploadPic.hidden = YES;

        self.imageEventPic.image =  info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }


    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    -(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
                 scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;

    }
```