# image name is null in UIImage in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     UIImage *image =[[UIImage alloc] init];
     image =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
     NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
     imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
     NSData *imageData;
     NSString *extensionOFImage =[imageName substringFromIndex:[imageName rangeOfString:@"."].location+1 ];

     if ([extensionOFImage isEqualToString:@"jpg"])
     {
          imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
     }
     else
     {
          imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
     }

     int imageSize=imageData.length/1024;
     NSLog(@"imageSize--->%d", imageSize);
     if (imageName!=nil) {
         NSLog(@"imageName--->%@",imageName);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"no image name found");
     }
     //commented ashok
     NSURL *resourceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
     resourceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
     ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
     [assetLibrary assetForURL:resourceURL
                  resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
           // get data
          ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
          CGImageRef cgImg = [assetRep fullResolutionImage];
          filename = [assetRep filename];
          NSLog(@"file name is:%@", filename);
     }
     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"%@", error);
     }];
}

-(void)send message
{
    NSLog(@"image name is:%@",filename);
      //image name is: IMG_0004.JPG       
    senderImgName=[UIImage imageNamed:filename];
    NSLog(@"sender image name is :%@",senderImgName);   
      //sender image name is: null
}
```

Comment: @BhavinRamani - file name is: IMG_0005.JPG

Comment: @BhavinRamani filename is string variable.. in filename having image name

Comment: Confirm that your image resources are added to your target.

Comment: @Desdenova actually i am picking image from photo gallery. so the image name should be passed here

Comment: @satya you are using imagePickerController ?

Comment: That changes things. `[UIImage imageNamed:filename]` will look for the image in the bundle. So it's perfectly normal if it comes as nil. You need to use `+ imageWithContentsOfFile:` with the image path.

Comment: @Signare yes i am using imagepickercontroller

Comment: @satya Check my answer

Comment: this will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674549/display-images-from-gallery-in-iphone

Comment: @Desdenova thanks for your response.. will you give me any idea///

Comment: @satya Object image is giving you data ?

Comment: @Signare no bro.. data getting nil

Comment: @satya what about cgImg  ?

Comment: if you are getting value in `cgImg`, then use `UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];`  Refer @Anessence answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `UIImage` object to the `imageView` not the name when you are using `UIImagePickerController`, Change your code like this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
     UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     self.imageView.image = image
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response.. but i am using objective-c.. will you post objective-c code'

Comment: @satya use my answer because singare has use deprecated method.

Comment: i am updating my query.. plz check it once

Comment: What do you want to do? Adding only code does not help us. Please specify what do you want to do after picking image from `ImagePicker`.

Comment: after picking the image from image picker i want to send the image to server.

Comment: Then you just need to convert your image in to data and encode it and send it the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116048/discussion-between-satya-and-nirav).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
//This will show the picker
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
//Deprecated In IOS6[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]; 
[picker release];
```

//This delegate method will give you the selected image.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    imgProfilePic.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: this method is deprecated.

Comment: @Signare i am update my query.. will you plz check it once

Comment: @Signare plz give me guidance.. i need your help

Answer (score 1):

Check if you added your image to the project.
If image exist in the project, check if it is included for using target in properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef cgImg = [assetRep fullResolutionImage];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
```

Comment: thanks for your response.. but i got error...will you give me some other ide

Comment: can u come to chat room i want to discuss with you