# ARC not retaining NSString in UIView subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

I have a parent view that allows you to see post in a `UITableView`. In its Navigation Bar I have a post button that when pressed presents a `UIView` subclass and shows it on the top of the screen. I have an image on that `UIView` that when tapped it presents the `UIImagePickerController` to allow users to pick an image to post to the service. I then convert the image to a string using `base64encoding` and everything is fine inside of that function if I use `NSLog` to do print outs.  However, when I go to post and call back to the `NSString` value from the `base64encoding` I get a null value.  It seems like ARC doesn't manage the same way in a `UIView` subclass as it does in a `UIViewController`, because this code works on a `viewController`, just not retaining on my subview.  Code is below... Any direction you can provide will be much appreciated, I have played with the properties for these values but nothings seems to make ARC retain it.
.h file

```
    @interface PostView: UIView
    {
        CGFloat animatedDistance;
        CGRect originalFrame;
        BOOL isShown;
        RESTURLDelagate *_connection;
        MBProgressHUD *HUD;
        NSMutableData *_data;
        NSData *imageData;
        UIAlertView *noConnection, *userSetup, *userExist, *accountAlertView, *confirmed, *login;
    }
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *postButton;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *attachedLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *characterLimit;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *attachImage;
    @property (strong) NSString *encodedImage;
    - (NSString *)Base64Encode:(NSData *)data;
    - (IBAction)postAction:(id)sender;

    - (void)show;
    - (void)hide;

    @end
```

.m file

```
    @implementation PostView

    @synthesize attachedLabel;
    @synthesize postButton;
    @synthesize textView;
    @synthesize characterLimit;
    @synthesize attachImage;
    @synthesize encodedImage;

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            originalFrame = frame;
            NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostView" owner:self options:nil];
            PostView *view = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [view setAlpha:0.7f];
            attachedLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(204, 212, 56, 21)];
            attachedLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [attachedLabel setText:@"Attached"];
            [attachedLabel setHidden:YES];
            attachedLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            attachedLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:12.0];
            characterLimit = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(246, 13, 50, 21)];
            [characterLimit setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
            characterLimit.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            characterLimit.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            characterLimit.font = [UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:12.0];
            attachImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 208, 30, 30)];
            [attachImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"attachphoto30x30.png"]];
            [self.textView setDelegate:self];
            [self.textView setAlpha:0.7f];
            [self.textView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [self.textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
            self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            [self addSubview:view];
            [self addSubview:characterLimit];
            [self addSubview:attachedLabel];
            [self addSubview:attachImage];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (IBAction)openCamera:(id)sender
    {
        UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [(ShamePostViewController *)[self.superview nextResponder] presentViewController:controller animated:YES                 
            completion:nil];
    }

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
    {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        //UIImage *scale = [image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 548.0f)];
        imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)];
        encodedImage = [self Base64Encode:imageData];
        [attachedLabel setHidden:NO];
    }

    - (void)show
    {
        //prepare attachImage
        attachImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapAttach = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openCamera:)];
        tapAttach.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self.attachImage addGestureRecognizer:tapAttach];


        isShown = YES;
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
        self.alpha = 0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"showAlert" context:nil];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
        self.alpha = 1;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    - (void)hide
    {
        isShown = NO;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideAlert" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hidePostView_Notification" object:nil];
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
        self.alpha = 0;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    - (void)toggle
    {
        if (isShown)
        {
            [self hide];
        } else
        {
            [self show];
        }
    }

    #pragma mark Animation delegate

    - (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
    {
        if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"showAlert"])
        {
            if (finished)
            {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        } else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"hideAlert"])
        {
            if (finished)
            {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                self.frame = originalFrame;
            }
        }
    }
    #pragma mark BaseEncode64

    - (NSString *)Base64Encode:(NSData *)data
    {
        //Point to start of the data and set buffer sizes
        int inLength = [data length];
        int outLength = ((((inLength * 4)/3)/4)*4) + (((inLength * 4)/3)%4 ? 4 : 0);
        const char *inputBuffer = [data bytes];
        char *outputBuffer = malloc(outLength);
        outputBuffer[outLength] = 0;

        //64 digit code
        static char Encode[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

        //start the count
        int cycle = 0;
        int inpos = 0;
        int outpos = 0;
        char temp;

        //Pad the last to bytes, the outbuffer must always be a multiple of 4
        outputBuffer[outLength-1] = '=';
        outputBuffer[outLength-2] = '=';

        while (inpos < inLength){
            switch (cycle) {
                case 0:
                    outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xFC)>>2];
                    cycle = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x03)<<4;
                    outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
                    cycle = 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xF0)>> 4];
                    temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x0F)<<2;
                    outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
                    cycle = 3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xC0)>>6];
                    cycle = 4;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x3f];
                    cycle = 0;
                    break;
                    default:
                    cycle = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        NSString *pictemp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outputBuffer];
        free(outputBuffer);
        return pictemp;
    }

    #pragma Submit action for posting
    - (IBAction)postAction:(id)sender
    {
        if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *noText = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Content" message:@"You must enter a message to post before submitting." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [noText show];
        }else
            if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"auth_id"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
            {
                _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
                URLSingleton *urls = [URLSingleton sharedInstance];
                REQUESTBuilderDelagate *rbd = [[REQUESTBuilderDelagate alloc] init];
                NSString *blob_ind = [[NSString alloc] init];
                NSLog(@"%@", encodedImage);
                "STRING IS NULL HERE"
                if ([encodedImage length] > 0)
                {
                    blob_ind = @"1";
                }else
                    blob_ind = @"0";

                NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"token", @"postMsg", @"active", @"blob", nil];
                NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]         
                    valueForKey:@"session_token"], textView.text, @"1", blob_ind, nil];
                [rbd createJSONRequest:keys values:values];
                [rbd setPostURL:urls.postMessage];

                _connection = [[RESTURLDelagate alloc] initWithRequest:rbd.getPostURL delegate:self];
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
                [_connection setDescription:@"PVCPOSTMSG"];
                HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self animated:YES];
                HUD.labelText = @"Posting...";
                [HUD setConnection:_connection];
                [_connection start];
                [postButton setEnabled:NO];
            }
            else
            {
                login = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication Required" message:@"Please login before attempting to post!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [login show];
                [textView setText:@""];
                [characterLimit setText:@"0/160"];
            }

    }

    #pragma Post Image
    -(void)postImage:(NSString *)shameID
    {
        if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"auth_id"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            URLSingleton *urls = [URLSingleton sharedInstance];
            REQUESTBuilderDelagate *rbd = [[REQUESTBuilderDelagate alloc] init];

            NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"token", @"encode64", @"active", @"SID", nil];
            NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                    valueForKey:@"session_token"], encodedImage, @"1", SID, nil];

            [rbd createJSONRequest:keys values:values];
            [rbd setPostURL:urls.imagePost];

            _connection = [[RESTURLDelagate alloc] initWithRequest:rbd.getPostURL delegate:self];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
            [_connection setDescription:@"PVCADDIMAGE"];
            HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self animated:YES];
            HUD.labelText = @"Attaching Image...";
            [postButton setEnabled:NO];
            [HUD setConnection:_connection];
            [_connection start];
        }
    }

    @end
```

Comment: encodedImage is what is not being retained.

Comment: what property you set for encodedImage?

Comment: property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *encodedImage;       I have tried retain and copy also with no luck.

Comment: Change the assign to retain or strong

Comment: Just edited my post to add the properties from the h file.

Comment: Just changed it to strong and I have also done retain with no luck.
Here is a NSLog of the encodeImage when I call it on the post button action.
2013-04-30 14:04:41.240 <APP NAME>[38028:907] (null)

Comment: When posting, again you are calling base64 encoding method? Can you give the posting method also?

Comment: Let me edit and just put the whole class m and h files in it

Comment: There is no variable named `encodedImage` in this code that I can see. The synthesized instance variable should be `_encodedImage`. How is this compiling? Do you declare an `encodedImage` variable somewhere?

Comment: Did you look at what I posted?  Look at the .h file

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but if you're going to go to the trouble of creating properties, then you should use them. You're accessing the ivars directly. You should delete any ivar declarations for which you also create properties, delete the @synthesize statements (this is all done automatically now by the compiler), and refer to your properties with self.propertyName.

Comment: I am always interested in understanding better different ways to code in objective-c.  I have changed to what you are saying and it is still not working..

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with ARC -- If you have encodedImage as a strong property of PostView, then that should not be deallocated as long as PostView is alive. I tried doing a modified version of your app, and logging the encodedImage (right after creation) took a long time, and seem to hang my app. Are you seeing this? If I commented out the base 64 code, and just returned a small string, it logged correctly in the postAction method.

Comment: If the image isn't scaled down and you try to do a nslog on the string it will hang xcode.

Comment: Can you post your sample code so I can see what you are doing in comparison to what I am doing?

Comment: @rdelmar can you please post your code so I can compare what you are doing?  Remember this is a UIView not a ViewController because I was able to get it working with the UIView Controller but that does not fit into my current model.

Comment: @Jarod: I did look at your .h file. It does not include an `encodedImage` instance variable, only a property with that name, which should create an ivar named `_encodedImage`. So where is this instance variable coming from?

Comment: Still null even after adding NSString *encodedImage to the h file

Comment: @Jarod: I'm not suggesting that you add an instance variable with that name. I'm saying that it sounds like you somehow have a variable you aren't accounting for floating around somewhere, because the line `encodedImage = [self Base64Encode:imageData]` should be an error but apparently isn't giving you one. Try taking out that instance variable, going to one of the places where you refer to `encodedImage` and jumping to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You just replace "encodedImage = [self Base64Encode:imageData];" with the line of code as given,

```
[self setEncodedImage:[self Base64Encode:imageData]];
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: When you are clicking the post button? After select an image or before selecting an Image?

Comment: After selecting the image.

Comment: After the image is selected in that function the NSString is assigned the result and I can do a NSLog to see that it is set to it.  However, ARC must not be retaining it after it is out of that function and it is being dealloc'd and not retained.  So when I call that encodedImage in the post button the object is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the property to `@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSString *encodedImage;` and  you should change the line `encodedImage = [self Base64Encode:imageData];` to `self.encodedImage =  [self Base64Encode:imageData];`

**EDIT**

So I saw this answer to a similar problem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13640603/2315974) so my last idea is that you should move

```
 UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     //UIImage *scale = [image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 548.0f)];
     imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)];
     encodedImage = [self Base64Encode:imageData];
    [attachedLabel setHidden:NO];
```

inside the completion block of the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method.

Comment: It is still null, I am wondering if it is because I am dismissing the Image Picker View Controller and ARC assumes that those objects can be dealloc.

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask, are you checking the nil value with `NSLog(@"%@",encodedImage)` ?

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing to see what is contained in the string and i get (null)

Comment: You should try with `NSLog(@"%@",self.encodedImage)` or check it with `po self.encodedImage` in XCode cmd line

Comment: Even moving it to the completion block it is still null.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a trial app based on yours, and it works ok. I added a smaller image to my camera roll on my phone, and now I get the string logging correctly in the postAction method (I copied the log statement to the top of the method since I didn't do anything with user defaults):

The only thing I changed in PostView was the postAction method. Here it is:

```
- (IBAction)postAction:(id)sender
{

     NSLog(@"EncodedImage is :%@", encodedImage);


    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        UIAlertView *noText = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Content" message:@"You must enter a message to post before submitting." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [noText show];
    }else
        if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"auth_id"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            //URLSingleton *urls = [URLSingleton sharedInstance];
            //REQUESTBuilderDelagate *rbd = [[REQUESTBuilderDelagate alloc] init];
            NSString *blob_ind = [[NSString alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"EncodedImage is :%@", encodedImage);
            //"STRING IS NULL HERE"
            if ([encodedImage length] > 0)
            {
                blob_ind = @"1";
            }else
                blob_ind = @"0";

            NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"token", @"postMsg", @"active", @"blob", nil];
            NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                                                valueForKey:@"session_token"], textView.text, @"1", blob_ind, nil];
            //[rbd createJSONRequest:keys values:values];
            //[rbd setPostURL:urls.postMessage];

            //_connection = [[RESTURLDelagate alloc] initWithRequest:rbd.getPostURL delegate:self];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
            //[_connection setDescription:@"PVCPOSTMSG"];
            //HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self animated:YES];
            //HUD.labelText = @"Posting...";
            //[HUD setConnection:_connection];
            //[_connection start];
            [postButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            login = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication Required" message:@"Please login before attempting to post!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [login show];
            [textView setText:@""];
            [characterLimit setText:@"0/160"];
        }

}
```

I put PostView on screen with this method in ViewController:

```
-(IBAction)addPostView:(id)sender {
    PostView *postView = [[PostView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:postView];
}
```

The .h file for PostView is the same as what you posted, except that I commented out a couple of ivars:

```
@interface PostView : UIView <UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    CGFloat animatedDistance;
    CGRect originalFrame;
    BOOL isShown;
    //RESTURLDelagate *_connection;
    //MBProgressHUD *HUD;
    NSMutableData *_data;
    NSData *imageData;
    UIAlertView *noConnection, *userSetup, *userExist, *accountAlertView, *confirmed, *login;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *postButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *attachedLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *characterLimit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *attachImage;
@property (strong) NSString *encodedImage;
- (NSString *)Base64Encode:(NSData *)data;
- (IBAction)postAction:(id)sender;

- (void)show;
- (void)hide;
```

Comment: Can you show your .h file for PostView and also how you are setting encodedImage in your .m file?

Comment: The only difference between our code is this line

pv = [[PostView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, 245)];

Comment: What iOS version are you testing this against?  I am during it on 6.1.3 on my iPhone to test the attaching of images.

Comment: @Jarod, I'm also using 6.1.3.

Comment: Should I start over from scratch.  Basically this app is in the app store and I am redoing the UI for v2.0 and it is involving a lot of deleting and adding of different views and I wonder if the project is just messed up in xcode since this works for you.

Comment: @Jarod, I can't really say. Without a overall knowledge of the app, I can't think what might be going wrong for you. This is a decision that you'll have to make.

Comment: Is there anyway we can sync up on a chat or something and I can work through this with you.  I just redid the app as a new project and it still didn't work.  So I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29216/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jarod)