# Cropping UIImagePickerController with overlay

Tags: ios, iphone, image, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to create an square overlay for a UIImagePickerController.

I have created a `NIB` with a top and bottom view which overlays the `UIImagePickerController` which works fine.

When the photo is taken, it seems that the ratio of the photo from height to width is 1.33333. However the ratio of the frame from height to width (on iphone 4s) is 1.5.

How can I get the exact `frame` of what the `UIImagePickerController` is taking a photo of? It can't be covering the whole screen, unless it is being stretched when added to the parent view.

I need the correct frame so I can crop the `image` that `UIImagePickerController` creates. I don't want to have the user crop the image manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found what the answer was, with the help of this post:

[How to crop UIImagePickerController taken picture as it is on display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932098/how-to-crop-uiimagepickercontroller-taken-picture-as-it-is-on-display)

It seems that the UIImagePickerController doesn't show the whole photo frame when the user is taking a photo.

In the case of the iPhone 4s, the image's sides are cut out. If you don't use an overlay, you can clearly see this after taking a photo.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a square overlay, use this:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

And to show a captured image in full screen, use this:

```
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
float imageWidth = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
float scale = ceilf((screenSize.height / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;

imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
```