# UIImagePickerController is it possible to show preview on same camera view

Tags: iphone, ios

By using UIImagePickerController is it possible to show more than one preview on buttom subview of camera view.

Comment: what do you mean i can not get you L:(

Comment: After took the photo, on that camera view itself i want to load the captured photo. Its possible?

Comment: use this delegate method - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088874/didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-return-nil-photo