# How can I retrieve the image taken using UIImagePickerControllerDelegate with ARC enabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that needs to take a picture and then show it to the user. I opened the camera to let the user take a picture using the following code:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Camera failed to open"
                          message: @"Camera is not available"
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

This present the camera view so the user can take a picture. I implemented the methods to handle the cancel and complete events like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage * image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [photoView setImage:image];
    [photoView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The problem is that after going through the last function, image is nil. At first dismissViewControllerAnimated was at the end of the function, but in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088874/didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-return-nil-photo) the answer explains that dismissViewControllerAnimated should be called first and picker should be released before getting the image from info. I tried putting dismissViewControllerAnimated at the top, but because I'm using ARC I cannot release picker.

How can I get the image from info?

Comment: The post suggests to you the block after dismissal is complete to get the image. did you try it ?

Comment: Use your code for getting an image before dismiss of controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `picker.allowsEditing = NO;` in your code. Then why are you retrieving the edited image? It won't exist. Anyways, if you allow editing, use this:

```
photoView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] ? info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] : info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
```

If the user has edited the photo, `photoView.image` will be set to the edited photo, otherwise it will be set to the original photo.

If you don't allow editing, simply retrieve the image using the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key.

Comment: It is not allowed to edit image `imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;` so it is needed to check only original image.

Comment: @selmad Sorry, didn't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. That's what I get for stupidly copy pasting stuff from the internet ><

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
// or UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Check in this method,

```
 (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)_picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
      NSLog(@"dictionary image info: %@",info );
    }
```

In this method, print the dictionary and check that are you getting **UIImagePickerControllerMediaType** and **UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage**. 
(In my case, I m getting value like this  **UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = UIImage: 0x1dd79520";**)

Now if you are getting value for **UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage** then you save value in this **UIImage**.

Now use this.

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
```

OR

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

Hope this will help you.