# imagePickerController with GPS data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I would like to thank if anyone could help. I am learning this very good swift sample code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztIBNHOm35E  or https://github.com/TDAbboud/PhotosGalleryApp

I am following the GPS data from selected Camera Roll photo. Which the App is need to use **imagePickerController** pick any photo and put in App Album. But the GPS data was missing from the following function (to pick photo from Camera Roll then put in the App Album).

My Question: Is how to use imagePickerController to include GPS to create photo/image in the new Album.

[image: Code Here]

```
//UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods 
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!){

     // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391158/getting-metadata-in-swift-by-uiimagepickercontroller?rq=1
    let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] as? NSDictionary //Try to get gps info
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    //Implement if allowing user to edit the selected image
    //let editedImage = info.objectForKey("UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage") as UIImage

      let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {
          PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
              let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
              let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
              let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset)!
            albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder!])
            }, completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    NSLog("Adding Image to Library -> %@", (success ? "Sucess":"Error!"))
                    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                  })
          })

      })
  }
  func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!){
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965299/write-uiimage-along-with-metadata-exif-gps-tiff-in-iphones-photo-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Remember to `import AssetsLibrary`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () in
        if (picker.sourceType == .PhotoLibrary) {
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
            var url: NSURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

            library.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: { (asset: ALAsset!) in
                    if asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) != nil {
                        let latitude = (asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) as! CLLocation!).coordinate.latitude
                        let longitude = (asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) as! CLLocation!).coordinate.longitude
                        println("\(latitude), \(longitude)")
                    }
                },
                failureBlock: { (error: NSError!) in
                    println(error.localizedDescription)
                })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!){
```

to

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
```