# Save metadata in swift4

Tags: metadata, swift4.1

I have searched many pages trying to find the code to save the metadata that is captured with an image using UIViewController, using Swift4.1

Is there a sample code that I can use for reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting metadata in swift by UIImagepickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391158/getting-metadata-in-swift-by-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: Have checked the link, and the coding described does not work for me on Swift 4.1.

After capturing the image, I am able to save the image, but not the metadata, could not find a way to recover it and save along with the image.