# Unabe to get image path & image from UIImagePicker in ios using simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get the image path & selected image from imagepicker controller.I have used delegate method for getting the path & image but i am always getting **null**.

**Code for showing imagepicker**

```
- (IBAction)choosePicture:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]
                                                 init];
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

**Code for delegate**

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
         didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                   editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    //You can retrieve the actual UIImage
    UIImage *pick_image = [editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSURL *path = [editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

**protocol code for view controller**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RegisterViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_fname;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_lname;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_profession;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_language;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_email;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_password;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_confirm_password;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_profile;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_address;

@end
```

Comment: What you get in pick_image?

Comment: Could either be linked to simulator, or linked to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088874/didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-return-nil-photo

Comment: You can already have image in pickercontroller < UIImage *pick_image = image >;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it better to use `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;`

like

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Below one is deprecated (you used)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 3_0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `[editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` inspite of `[editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];` this will give you the path of the image.

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is for movies.